# Execute AT command from browser when someone access my page

Tags: php, apache, system, at-job

I need to execute AT command from browser. My /etc/at.deny is empty and /etc/at.allow does not exists. I could execute "php page.php" on command line with any user and works fine.

Here is my page (page.php):

```
<?php
exec('at -f job.txt now + 1 minutes'); 
?>
```

My job.txt:

```
/bin/php /var/www/html/my_job.php
```

So now I wan't to execute page.php when someone access my page.php from their browser:

```
https://mywebpage.com/page.php
```

I got this error "PAM failure: System error"  from /var/log/httpd/error_log when someone access my page. I guess that this error is caused by permission issue, could someone please tell me how fix it or give me some suggestion. I can't found any answer or example online.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Barmar reminded me that I should use full path. And now this is my new page.php, but I still getting same error "PAM failure". Any suggestion please?

```
<?php
exec('at -f /var/www/html/job.txt now + 1 minutes');
>?
```

I think that the main problem is AT command. If I remove the AT command and using 'sh' command it will work.

```
exec('sh /var/www/html/job.txt');
```

**UPDATE:**

So finally I found the problem, the SELinux block the apache to use atd command. Now I don't get "PAM failure" in error_log anymore after I set my SELinux to Permissive. However, I still getting some error, my /var/log/httpd/error_log appear 'job 47 at Sat May 26 22:38:00 2018', everything seem okay but my_job.php didn't works. Why? Did I miss something?

Comment: Try using the full pathname of `job.txt`. It's probably not in the current directory of the PHP process.

Comment: @Barmar Hi thanks for your answer! Yes you pointed out one mistake I made. But I still getting the same error PAM failure :(

Comment: What's in `job.txt`?